# Change background color and image whilst hovering over 3 separate tiles/buttons

Tags: javascript

Currently my code is set to change background colors when I hover over 3 separate tiles. So far its working as expected but when I am trying to change the background image of a div nothing is happening.

p.s. I am a complete beginner and so far I am experimenting with code, I am aware that down the line I should create variables/functions in order to avoid callback hell

```
$("#basecamp-background").mouseover(function(){
  $("body").css("background-color", "red", function(){
    $(".dashboard").css("background-image", "url(images/1.png)");
  });
});
```

First time posting here, not sure if the code will be displayed with the appropriate indentation, however I can assure you that it is.

Looking to change the background color and image when you hover over different tiles/buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing a closing bracket for one of the function statements, but I will assume that is just a typo in your question. The real issue is that you haven't formatted the `background-image` css value correctly.

Here is what it should say:

```
$(".dashboard").css("background-image", "url('images/1.png1')")
```

The url to your image has to be wrapped in quotes of its own. Using single quotes will fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The css function of jquery doesn't have a 3th funtion paramter. You can place all code in the event handler function.

Also I recommend to use mouseenter event instead of mouseover. Mouseenter fires only once per time the user moves his mouse into the element. Mouseover will fire a lot of times when the user moves their mouse over the element.

```js
$("#basecamp-background").on("mouseenter", function() {
  $("body").css("background-color", "red");
  $(".dashboard").css('background-image', "url('https://dummyimage.com/100x100/00f/f00')");
});
```

```css
.dashboard {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="basecamp-background">hover this</div>
<div class="dashboard">testdiv</div>
```